# How to define on Drupal an external database specifying the schema

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, settings

I want to connect Drupal to an external Database and i need to specify the schema otherwise Drupal schema module connects by default the 'public' schema. I tried, whithout succes with the following code:

```
 $databases['conservation']['default'] = array(
     'database' => 'conservation',
     'schema' => 'projects_test1',
      'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'password' => 'xxx',
      'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
      'port' => '5432',
      'driver' => 'pgsql',
      'prefix' => array(
     'default'   => 'projects_test1.',
     'users'     => 'shared.',
     'sessions'  => 'shared.',
     'role'      => 'shared.',
     'authmap'   => 'shared.',
   )

);
```

I have done some googling but haven't found anybody trying to do this as yet.
Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to connect your Drupal site to external DataBase:

```
   $databases['conservation']['default'] = array(
     'database' => 'conservation',
     'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
     'password' => 'xxx',
     'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
     'port' => '5432',
     'driver' => 'pgsql',
     'prefix' => array(
       'default'   => 'projects_test1.',
       'users'     => 'shared.',
       'sessions'  => 'shared.',
       'role'      => 'shared.',
       'authmap'   => 'shared.',
     )    
  );
```

Above code specifies the conservation DB configuration for Drupal. So when you need to query this other database in your modules, you have to switch the connection to it with this function

```
<?php
db_set_active('your_other_db');
?>
```

When you are finished, you have to close it and revert back to the default database connection in order for Drupal to be able to access its data

```
<?php
db_set_active();
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to create a module but i just want to use the "schema module to be able to visualize data using the data tables module.

Comment: Ah! you can try Schema and Data Tables to able to create views of external data visualization in drupal 7. Hope this help :)